# second image in footer and styling

Tags: wordpress, styles, stylesheet, footer

I have my wordpress theme built but there are 2 problems, the first the twitter feed I have in my footer (not a widget) is taking the styling for something else instead of the styling I gave it. I styled the links etc for the feed but it's not styling properly. Also I want to have an image behind my footer but not be part of it. In my site I have my footer image that repeats horizontally and an image behind it. My issue is when I put the image in it acts like part of the footer and not the background (it's not my background image just on top of it). Here is a link to my blog (the code is too long to post here):

http://blog.zombiesarefierce.com/

also here is a pic of what my footer is supposed to look like, any help would be greatly appreciated:

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/jq19y

Answer (score 0):

download addon fire bug

Right click on image and click on inspect eliment with fire bug then chang the css of your image
in your case

```
.art-footer img
{
border-width: 1px;
}
```

and make it

```
 border-width: 0px;
```

n here is the screen shot of your site
[image]